# windows - reg add ignores /f

Tags: batch-file, registry

The title says it all.

Code:

```
REG add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\" /f /t REG_DWORD /v "SystemRestore" /d 0 /f
```

It works when you execute it once but 2nd time it askes for prompt.

I found this page but not worked.

[Link:](https://superuser.com/questions/1198757/reg-add-ignores-f) https://superuser.com/questions/1198757/reg-add-ignores-f

Btw i am not going to be online. Ill look in 1 day. Thanks.

Comment: Which `/f`doesn't work, the first one or the second? Are you running it `As administrator`? `Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT" /V SystemRestore /T REG_DWORD /D 0 /F`. _there's nothing more motivating than being asked to work on someone else's problem, while they disappear for a day without providing all the details!_

Comment: Furthermore, had you actually read the OP's own comment below the only answer to that linked question, you'd have seen `One was the trailing backslash in the second line is interpreted as an escape character`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
REG add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT" /t REG_DWORD /v "SystemRestore" /d 0 /f
```

Remove the trailing backslash from the *KeyName* as a backslash is used to escape a double quote on a command line. Also remove the duplicate argument of `/f` which can cause an error.

Repeated use does not prompt with testing the change.

Comment: *»[...] as a backslash is used to escape a double quote on a command line.«* This is not really true, the command line (`cmd`) does not treat the `\ `as an escape character, it's actually `reg.exe`...

Comment: didnt notice that there is a \ for nothing (spare). Thank you.

Comment: I'm using system() function in C++ to run reg.exe so I have to use backslash to escape the double quote marks, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on one machine where the following prompts even with /f

```
"reg add "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v "Path" /d "C:\Git\usr\bin;C:\Git\cmd;c:\program files (x86)\common files\oracle\java\javapath;c:\git2\usr\bin;c:\git2\cmd;c:\programs\orant\11.2.0.3.0.x64\bin;c:\programs\orax86\12.1.0.2.0.x86\bin;c:\program files\tibco\tibrv\8.2\bin;c:\programs\orant\11.2.0.3.0\bin;c:\windows\system32;c:\windows;c:\windows\system32\wbem;c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;c:\program files\microsoft sql server\110\tools\binn" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f"
```

The keyname has no trailing backslash and I also do not see another problem here.

Answer: The solution was to remove the quotation marks from the value, e.g. `/v Path` instead of `/v "Path"`

Comment: Didn't work for me.